# How to package and share a final version of a Visual Studio Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, share, send

I'm trying to share a Visual Studio Windows Forms Application with people but I don't know how I can export my project into a zip file that I can send to others.

Comment: are you trying to share the code?  Just zip it in file explorer outside VS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In solution explorer I went to (Restock Alerter)>publish and published the project to a folder on my desktop that I can send

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share the code:

1. Right-Click on the solution name
2. Open Location In File Explorer
3. Ctrl-A > Right-Click > Send-To > Zip

If you want it in a app format:

1. Right-Click the startup project
2. Publish